# Quarkus with Camel call external endpoint. Error: Map at least one servlet to a path using quarkus.camel.servlet.url-patterns

Tags: java, apache-camel, quarkus

I'm trying to implement a Camel to supply microservices applications, I want to call a HTTP route with my own headers with token, alias & etc. firstly I want to call an external endpoint like "http://outside.endpoint.com" and recive the JSON Response to treat the object internally.

My error:

```
2021-10-24 18:52:08,519 INFO  [org.jbo.threads] (main) JBoss Threads version 3.4.2.Final
2021-10-24 18:52:08,981 ERROR [io.qua.dep.dev.IsolatedDevModeMain] (main) Failed to start quarkus: java.lang.RuntimeException: io.quarkus.builder.BuildException: Build failure: Build failed due to errors
    [error]: Build step org.apache.camel.quarkus.component.servlet.deployment.ServletProcessor#build threw an exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Map at least one servlet to a path using quarkus.camel.servlet.url-patterns or quarkus.camel.servlet.[your-servlet-name].url-patterns
    at org.apache.camel.quarkus.component.servlet.deployment.ServletProcessor.build(ServletProcessor.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.ExtensionLoader$2.execute(ExtensionLoader.java:820)
    at io.quarkus.builder.BuildContext.run(BuildContext.java:277)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextHandler$1.runWith(ContextHandler.java:18)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2449)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1478)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:501)

    at io.quarkus.runner.bootstrap.AugmentActionImpl.runAugment(AugmentActionImpl.java:418)
    at io.quarkus.runner.bootstrap.AugmentActionImpl.createInitialRuntimeApplication(AugmentActionImpl.java:276)
    at io.quarkus.runner.bootstrap.AugmentActionImpl.createInitialRuntimeApplication(AugmentActionImpl.java:67)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.IsolatedDevModeMain.firstStart(IsolatedDevModeMain.java:92)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.IsolatedDevModeMain.accept(IsolatedDevModeMain.java:441)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.IsolatedDevModeMain.accept(IsolatedDevModeMain.java:65)
    at io.quarkus.bootstrap.app.CuratedApplication.runInCl(CuratedApplication.java:137)
    at io.quarkus.bootstrap.app.CuratedApplication.runInAugmentClassLoader(CuratedApplication.java:93)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.DevModeMain.start(DevModeMain.java:145)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.DevModeMain.main(DevModeMain.java:63)
Caused by: io.quarkus.builder.BuildException: Build failure: Build failed due to errors
    [error]: Build step org.apache.camel.quarkus.component.servlet.deployment.ServletProcessor#build threw an exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Map at least one servlet to a path using quarkus.camel.servlet.url-patterns or quarkus.camel.servlet.[your-servlet-name].url-patterns
    at org.apache.camel.quarkus.component.servlet.deployment.ServletProcessor.build(ServletProcessor.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.ExtensionLoader$2.execute(ExtensionLoader.java:820)
    at io.quarkus.builder.BuildContext.run(BuildContext.java:277)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextHandler$1.runWith(ContextHandler.java:18)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2449)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1478)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:501)

    at io.quarkus.builder.Execution.run(Execution.java:116)
    at io.quarkus.builder.BuildExecutionBuilder.execute(BuildExecutionBuilder.java:79)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.QuarkusAugmentor.run(QuarkusAugmentor.java:160)
    at io.quarkus.runner.bootstrap.AugmentActionImpl.runAugment(AugmentActionImpl.java:416)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Map at least one servlet to a path using quarkus.camel.servlet.url-patterns or quarkus.camel.servlet.[your-servlet-name].url-patterns
    at org.apache.camel.quarkus.component.servlet.deployment.ServletProcessor.build(ServletProcessor.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.ExtensionLoader$2.execute(ExtensionLoader.java:820)
    at io.quarkus.builder.BuildContext.run(BuildContext.java:277)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextHandler$1.runWith(ContextHandler.java:18)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2449)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1478)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:501)

2021-10-24 18:52:08,981 INFO  [io.qua.dep.dev.IsolatedDevModeMain] (main) Attempting to start live reload endpoint to recover from previous Quarkus startup failure
2021-10-24 18:52:09,257 INFO  [org.jbo.threads] (main) JBoss Threads version 3.4.2.Final
```

My application.properties:

```
quarkus.http.port= 8056

camel.component.servlet.mapping.context-path=/services/*
quarkus.camel.servlet.servlet-name=CamelServlet
```

My dependecies of pom.xml:

```
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
                <artifactId>${quarkus.platform.artifact-id}</artifactId>
                <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <!--    CAMEL        -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-quarkus-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-quarkus-rest</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-quarkus-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-jackson</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <version>1.18.20</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-arc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-junit5</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

My route that there are the camel-rest call to execute the *getCompanies* bean:

```
package com.example.control;

import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.model.rest.RestBindingMode;

import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@ApplicationScoped
public class CompanyRouter extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() {
        restConfiguration().component("restlet")
                .host("localhost").port("8056")
                .bindingMode(RestBindingMode.auto);;

        rest("/api/people")
        // HTTP: GET /api
                .get()
                .outType(Response.class)
                .to("bean:getCompaniesBean"); // This will invoke the bean
    }
}
```

my bean to call the method *listCompanies*:

```
package com.example.control;

import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@ApplicationScoped
public class GetCompaniesBean {

    public Response listCompanies() {

        return Response.ok("Joinha!").build();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to use the default `CamelHttpTransportServlet`, then you can supply a minimal configuration and just set `quarkus.camel.servlet.url-patterns`. For example:

```
quarkus.camel.servlet.url-patterns = /services/*
```

There's more information in the documenation here:

https://camel.apache.org/camel-quarkus/latest/reference/extensions/servlet.html#_additional_camel_quarkus_configuration

Unless you really need use servlets, it's probably better & simpler to use the `platform-http` component as your HTTP consumer:

https://camel.apache.org/camel-quarkus/latest/reference/extensions/platform-http.html